# Generic collection MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Hi All I have trying to use this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_aspnetmvc3fundamentals_topic8.aspx, but i have some question

1) my collection under Create t.Albums is always empty however my t.Genre is working
i am not sure how to fix the problem i've included this in my Create.aspx

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<SomeStore.Controllers.ViewModels.StoreBrowseViewModel>"
```

----------------`StoreBrowseViewModel`----------------

```
public class StoreBrowseViewModel
{
    public StoreBrowseViewModel{}

    public StoreBrowseViewModel(List<Album> _Albums, Genre _Genre)
    {
        this.Genre=_Genre;
        this.Albums = _Albums;
    }
    public Genre Genre { get; set; }
    public List<Album> Albums { get; set; }
}
```

----------------`StoreBrowseController`----------------

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Genre,Albums")]StoreBrowseViewModel t)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collections are not bound by ModelBinder. What do you need that for?

Comment: I am listing different classes in my form  so it can be filled out. Should i create a new class without this collection? In reality for this form I don’t need a collection, i was reusing this class...

Comment: If you don't need that collection, just ignore the fact it is empty. But I don't understand how `StoreBrowseViewModel` can be filled in form, because it is obviously a browse-only viewmodel. And yes, you should try to create specific viewmodels for each task, that would make your intent clearer.